# How can jsPDF be used to create pdf of output, 'exactly' as window.print() command gives out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

How can jsPDF be used to create pdf of output, 'exactly' as window.print() command gives out?

I have to create a pdf of 'div' element which I tried using jsPDF. But the output I get has lot of extra bullets and messed up numbering. But what I see on screen is well formatted 'div' which I am able to print exactly as it is by usng window.print().

My only complain is that I want another option of saving this output in pdf for users who will not be able to change the option in print to 'save to pdf'.

```
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var source = $('#content')[0]; //content has the survey with lot of linked list elements and various formatted text
    //I tried all kind of formatting on 'source' to make it right... but its not possible to keep the form as it is what it looks on screen
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, {// y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                //'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },
    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Disclosure' + '@DateTime.Now' + '.pdf');
    }
    , margins);
```

So, is there a way to save the output in PDF as it looks after window.print()?

Comment: were you able to figure this out @TygerEye

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
var source = $('#content')[0];
var options = { background: '#fff' };

pdf.addHTML(source, options, function()
{
     pdf.save('Disclosure' + '@DateTime.Now' + '.pdf');
});
```

(The background option is needed if you're dealing with single elements such as a div as you've mentioned, because otherwise you'll get a transparent/black background)

Also note you'll need [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) for this to work.

Comment: I get this error: pdf.addHTML is not a function @diegcor